# How to solve DLL modules with different CPU types?

Tags: python-3.x, dll, dependencies

I am trying to run a code on python to communicate with the software Vrep using the B0 remote API, I have 2 computers and in one i can run it with no issues, but when i run the code in another computer the output shows:
'self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found'

I have already searched around for solutions and downloaded the DependencyWalker software to debug this issue. and you could check the results on the Dependency walker file i attached.

The only difference is that i have dependencies with different CPU version. when the system in both pcs is the same.

My question is.
Do you know how i could solve the issue for these dependencies with different CPU version.
Thanks.

DLL file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bNRaMHmXkcYH_c9kAdo6Dz0uBPlp7BXA

DependencyWalker file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hjyd5tQlAZkL52gPBbaoKI4zkl1-Yz99

Comment: What do you mean by "different CPU version" - 32-bit vs 64-bit?

Comment: @rhughes, yes that's correct